# tinyMCE - Filemanager and ImageManager integration (PHP)

Tags: php, tinymce

i started using tinyMCE, and got a copy of the filemanager and imagemanager from a fellow coder, so i could try them before buying.

I'm using CodeIgniter, but right now i'm trying to configure it in a clean html index file on the root of my server. the wysiwyg works perfectly, ImageManager works perfectly but i can't seem to run FileManager: ([screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/tQCswdXgVr3)).

I've debugged the process, line by line, but  can't understand how the invocation of "pages/fm/index.html" work because of all those variables like `{#common.directory}` . I think my problem is in the config.php file, because when i debug the process, everything works well until this last condition in index.php:

```
if ($man->isAuthenticated()) {
        $man->dispatchEvent("onInit");
        header("Location: pages/". $config["general.theme"] ."/" . $page . $suffix);
        die();
} else {
        header("Location: ". $config["authenticator.login_page"] . "?return_url=" . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        die();
}
```

it verifies `($man->isAuthenticated)`, the header Location url is well resolved to the above mentioned `"pages/fm/index.html"` but in firebug i get the error:
[image: Firebug error]

As i said before, Imagemanager follows a pretty similar process, and all is working well.

Thank you very much

Comment: it looks like those stuff in brackets are translation placeholders, so I would start the investigation around language files

Answer (score 1):

I cant figure out the issue you have mentioned here. I am using the [tinybrowser](http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php) plugin for managing images and medias. Its working fine in my project.